# REST API Basic Auth is failing in AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I am calling REST API Post method using AWS Lambda function. But the basic authentication failed. same code worked fine on pycharm. Could anyone pleasehelp.

Please find below sample code

```
***import json
import os
import sys
import logging
import argparse
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import datetime
import time
import json
import base64
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def lambda_handler(event, context):  
    head = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
            'Authorization': 'c2Vn6Z1oxK3R3Q18='
        }
    body = f"""<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
            <ServiceRequest>
            <filters>           
                </filters>
             <preferences>
             <startFromOffset>1</startFromOffset>    
             <limitResults>1</limitResults>
              </preferences>
            </ServiceRequest>"""
            
    request_URL='https:'
    
    response = requests.post(request_URL, headers=head, data=body)
    print(response.text) 
                           
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }***
```

Getting below output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https:">
<responseCode>INVALID_CREDENTIALS</responseCode>
<responseErrorDetails>
<errorMessage>HTTP BASIC AUTH header is malformed.</errorMessage>
</responseErrorDetails>
</ServiceResponse>
```

Same code gives xml response as output when i executed on Pycharm.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your markup to add syntax highlighting to your code blocks? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to do so. (Note: please do not replace your code block with an image of your IDE. [That would be worse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541))

Answer (score 0):

Your Authorisation header should be something like

```
'Authorization': 'Basic c2Vn6Z1oxK3R3Q18='
```

Comment: Hi Vikram S, Thanks for your suggestion, i have tried this as well but still getting same issue.

Comment: The basic token value you entered is it dummy or actual, as the token needs to be base64 encode of username:password. the value 'dGVzdDp0ZXN0MTIz' is base 64 encode of username 'test' and password 'test123'.  Also can you try same request through curl or postman

Comment: The token value which i have posted here is dummy one. i tried in postman as well as on pycharm, its working fine